# What is a Human Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Human Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Human Words™ | Not Human Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| PARITY | EQUALITY |
| MAXIMUM | MINIMUM |
| INCURIOUS | CURIOUS |
| PALACE | CASTLE |
| MALL | HALL |
| LUMBER | WOOD |
| CAPITAL | EXPENSE |
| PATENT | PROPRIETARY |
| TRAPDOOR | TURNSTILE |
| METADATA | INDEX |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Human Words™,Not Human Words™
PARITY,EQUALITY 
MAXIMUM,MINIMUM 
INCURIOUS,CURIOUS 
PALACE,CASTLE 
MALL,HALL 
LUMBER,WOOD 
CAPITAL,EXPENSE 
PATENT,PROPRIETARY 
TRAPDOOR,TURNSTILE 
METADATA,INDEX
```

Hint 1:

> [image]

Comment: CSV version: hALL small letter h intended?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Human Word is a word where:

> The first 4 letters also begin the name of one or more bones in the human body.

Like so:

> **PARI**TY = **PARI**etal
>  **MAXI**MUM = **MAXI**lla
>  **INCU**RIOUS = **INCU**s
>  **PALA**CE = **PALA**tine
>  **MALL** = **MALL**eus
>  **LUMB**ER = **LUMB**ar (vertebrae)
>  **CAPI**TAL = **CAPI**tate
>  **PATE**NT = **PATE**lla
>  **TRAP**DOOR = **TRAP**ezium / **TRAP**ezoid
>  **META**DATA = **META**tarsal/**META**carpal

The hint was helpful, as:

> 'Tissue' got me thinking about other components of the human body, leading me to bones.

Comment: rot13(Vs gur cnggrea vf bayl gur svefg guerr yrggref, UHZna == UHZrehf.)